# Force an SMS to use an Area Code

Tags: sms, 4.2-jelly-bean

My brother's phone number requires an area code to send an SMS.  I keep getting a message back to use an area code, but I can't find any way to force Android to use it.

I'm using 4.2.2

Comment: does the contact info phone number have the area code entered or do you just have the phone number because he has the same area code?

Comment: It looks to me like it has area code both on the phone and in my gmail contacts.

Comment: Try manually entering the phone number when sending an SMS message, including the area code, and see if that message goes through.

Comment: It sees my brothers contact and still sends it without :(

Comment: try deleting the number from contact, and then send to just the number including the area code. if it works, then re-add the number to the contact with the area code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read, there's some caching that makes this difficult, but basically you need to add +1 Area code.  Here's the exact steps I do to make sure this works, it's a pain to do it when you run into a number that's bad, but I'm too lazy to preemptively fix up my address book. But maybe I should.

1. Delete all messages related to the person, if it was a phone call,
   I'd delete the call log as well.
2. Hit your home key button to get to your home screen
3. Hold down your home key button to open a list of running Apps (Some carriers
   disable this I think)
4. Close all of your apps dealing with contacts, dialing and messaging.
5. Go into system Settings > Storage (I get there by hitting the menu key from the home screen)
6. Clear all of your cached data, there's a button on the storage screen.
7. Go back in to your contacts and edit the contact you just dialed.
8. Add +1 Area Code before the number (i.e. +1 555 555 5555)
9. Go back and try dialing by looking them up in the Address book

This works for me.  There is some caching that happens, which is why I do it in this order.  Hope it helps.